# How to find an unknown matrix which when multiplied with a vector gives the cross product of 2 vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvvJ8.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvvJ8.png)

I am trying to find the matrix $[u]_x$ as shown in the image. $u \times v$ is easy to calculate but how do I find the matrix $[u]_x$ such that $[u]_x v = u \times v$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u \times v
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        i  &  j  &  k \\
       u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\
       v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        u_2v_3 - u_3v_2 \\ u_3v_1 - u_1v_3 \\ u_1v_2 - u_2v_1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    &=\begin{bmatrix}
          0 & -u_3 &  u_2 \\
        u_3 &    0 & -u_1 \\
       -u_2 &  u_1 &  0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks I finally understood that the vector cross product can also be represented as a product of skew-symmetric matrix and a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The $n \times n$ matrix $A$ corresponding to a linear transformation $T$ of $\mathbb R^n$ (so that $Av = Tv$ for all column vectors $v$ with $n$ entries)
has columns $T e_1, \ldots, T e_n$ where $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^n$.  So what does $[u]_x$ do to each of $\pmatrix{1\cr 0 \cr 0\cr}$, $\pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr 0\cr}$, $\pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 1\cr}$?

Answer (score 0):

In three dimensions antisymmetric matrices and vectors are in one-to-one correspondence. For each vector $\mathbf{u}$ there is a unique antisymmetric matrix $U$ such that
$$
U\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v},\qquad\forall\mathbf{v}\in V
$$
and vice-versa.

To find the relation between $U$ and $\mathbf{u}$, take into account that the preceding relation can be written in index notation (summation convention implied)
$$
U_{ij}v_j=e_{ikj}u_kv_j
$$
so that
$$
U_{ij}=e_{ikj}u_k=-e_{ijk}u_k
$$
The inverse relation is obtained multiplying by $e_{ijh}$ and summing on $i,j$
$$
e_{ijh}U_{ij}=-e_{ijh}e_{ijk}u_k=-2\delta_{hk}u_k=-2u_h
$$
i.e.
$$
u_h=-\frac{1}{2}e_{hij}U_{ij}
$$